# Modify form params before saving in the database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app form, I have text field where user type ip address in ip_v4 format, but type of ip_address is text. Column type in IpAddress model is of inet type in my postgresql database. However, if I want to save ip_address_params, I have to cast string represenation of ip address (e.g. "192.168.0.1" to IPAddr object
What is the best way to modify param[param][param] before setting strong params? Should I add before_action in my controller?

Comment: Think fat models, skinny controllers. I think this is something you can set at the model level in a before_create action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use attribute setter in your model:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.ip_text=(val)
    self.ip = IPAddr.new(val)
  end

  def self.ip_text
    self.ip.to_s
  end
end
```

Then use `ip_text` in your params instead of `ip`:

```
 f.text :ip_text
```

Or, vice versa, use `ip` in your params, but change database column name to `ip_source` or something else, if you prefer so.